# Crear una tabla en HTML con php consultando una base de datos.Cual es la mejor opcion?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php


require "conexion.php";

$conexion = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$baseDatos);

if($conexion->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Error de conexion de la base datos".$conexion->connect_error;
    exit();
}
$sql = "select * from medicos";

$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">LISTADO DE MEDICOS</h1>
    <table width="70%" border="1px" align="center">

    <tr align="center">
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Identificacion</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Apellidos</td>
        <td>Especialidad</td>
        <td>Telefono</td>
        <td>Correo</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $datos["idMedico"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["medIdentificacion"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["medNombres"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["medApellidos"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["medEspecialidad"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["medTelefono"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["medCorreo"]?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php   
        }

     ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué tiene de malo la manera actual? Te incomoda tener tantas etiquetas `<?php ?>` ?

Comment: El código parece correcto. Pero... En SQL se recomienda usar en el SELECT solo aquellas columnas que necesitamos, con el SELECT * aunque sea más cómodo casi siempre pides columnas que nunca usarás. Usando * tu código no queda optimizado,  y eso se nota cuando la aplicación o la BD crece.

Comment: si no te gusta de esa manera puedes hacerlo asi <td><?= $datos["idMedico"]?></td>

Answer (score 2):

tu codigo esta bien pero para ordenar haz lo siguiente: 
require "conexion.php"; debe teber todos los parametro de conexion incluso el error por tanto el siguiente codigo deberia anexarlos al archivo

```
$conexion = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$baseDatos);

if($conexion->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Error de conexion de la base datos".$conexion->connect_error;
    exit();
}
```

tambien como te menciono **A Cedano** por cuestiones de optimizacion de querys debes agregar los campos al select

```
select idMedico,medIdentificacion,medNombres,medApellidos,medEspecialidad,medTelefono,medCorreo from medicos
```

Con respecto a la tabla yo la haria de esta forma, como te explique en el comentario

```
    <tr>
        <td><?=$datos["idMedico"]?></td>
        <td><?=$datos["medIdentificacion"]?></td>
        <td><?=$datos["medNombres"]?></td>
        <td><?=$datos["medApellidos"]?></td>
        <td><?=$datos["medEspecialidad"]?></td>
        <td><?=$datos["medTelefono"]?></td>
        <td><?=$datos["medCorreo"]?></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

La opción que elegiste es válida, otra forma de hacerlo que es mas claro de leer sin tanta apertura y cierre de tags php seria

```
    while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){
    echo'
        <tr>
            <td>'.$datos["idMedico"].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos["medIdentificacion"].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos["medNombres"].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos["medApellidos"].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos["medEspecialidad"].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos["medTelefono"].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos["medCorreo"].'</td>
        </tr>';

    }

 ?>
```